# Python 3 - Can't concat to str with data from API

Tags: python, json, urllib

I am currently using Python 3 to develop a tool which makes use of an API. The way this API works is that it is delivered through http requests from URLs. The idea behind this script is that it scrapes all of the urls for data and then merges all of these data into one json file.

When running the script I am presented with the following traceback:

```
File "/home/usr/anaconda3/envs/apitool/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", 
line 1064, in _send_output
+ b'\r\n'
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

I understand from looking at previous questions that http requests are done in bytes and JSON is stored in strings. That makes sense and I have tried to explicitly convert the bytes to utf-8 strings but still get the error.

I am completely new to Python so please forgive me if this looks really basic. 
I have tried to follow previous solutions but none of them have worked for me so far.

Thank you in advance!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

URLs = [
# Some URLs that return JSON objects

]

json_list = []

for url in URLs:
   resp = urlopen(url, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 
   Safari/537.36'})
   resp = resp.read().decode(resp.headers.get_content_charset() or 'utf-8')
   json_list.append(json.loads(resp))
   with open("abc.json", 'w') as fp:
       json.dump(json_list, fp, indent=2)
```

Comment: Try using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). The response object has a great `.json()` method

Comment: @Ricardo thank you for sending that, it seems to make more sense. Although, it's not clear how to solve this problem yet. Does this module explicitly convert bytes to strings by itself or do I still need to do that myself? I've changed the library call at the top and the bottom code to 'requests.get' but now I am getting an error about inconsistent spacing and indentation. I'm so confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

This code merges all the `JSON` received from the urls into one `final.json` file.

```
import requests
import json

urls = ["https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random", 
        "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random"]

final_data = {}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36'}

for url in urls:
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    final_data.update(data)

with open('final.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(final_data, f)
```

Comment: This makes much more sense! Thank you. The API I am using requires me to pass the user-agent as part of the http request. Does this go with 'final_data[url, {user-agent: blabla}]?

Comment: @Stig0501 Headers added now!

Comment: The `final_data` dict doesn't require any  `{'user-agent': }`. This is only passed has argument in `requests.get(url, headers=headers)`

Comment: @Stig0501 Try my code with your JSON urls and see the result!

Comment: Great that it helped :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, is there a way to get it so each api call/json record is recorded to its own row rather than one?

Comment: Use
`data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()`
And `final_data.update(data)` instead of `final_data[url] ... `

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have changed my code to this: for url in URLs:
 final_data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
 final_data = final_data.update(final_data)                                                      This generates a JSON file but it is null. Have I misinterpreted your suggestion?

Comment: We seem to be getting somewhere now. It is saving the json data into the format that I want but the problem is that it each row is overwriting each other so the resulting file only has one row but with json data from the last api call if that makes sense?